# SQL Server cyrillic error in php

Tags: php, sql-server, utf-8

First of all I want to apologize to my bad English.

And now for my problem. I have a SQL Server database and I want to get data from it with php. I can execute just select queries, because the database is not on localhost. I must get data from this database and the data is in cyrillic. This is my problem. When I execute `mssql_query` and get data, the Cyrillic symbols are returned as `????`.

I try to convert characters with `iconv` and `mb_convert_string`, but without success.

Does anybody have a similar problem and how have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the cyrillic language pack installed on the web server and your client computer?  If you can connect to the SQL Server directly you might want to just export the data from the SQL Server using the BCP command line utility.

What is the end goal that you are going for?

Answer (score 0):

If the returned characters are actually question marks then you the problem may have been at the DB end with the data having been incorrectly imported.  In this case there may be little you can do.

If the returned characters are just being displayed as question marks, check the actual bytes (e.g. by using `bin2hex` on the string) and use that to determine the encoding that you have received.  You'll need to inform `iconv` of the correct encoding otherwise its "garbage in, garbage out".

Comment: I try iconv(mb_detect_encoding($d['catname']), 'utf-8', $d['catname']), mb_convert_encoding($d['catname'], 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($d['catname'])) and echo $d['catname'], and I have just ????  when I try bin2hex($d['catname']) I have 3f3f3f3f3f

Comment: If you're seeing 3F bytes in your original string it's already too late to do any conversion; the data is already lost.